# Issue in Adding namespace to java class root element

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using jaxb to convert a java object to xml. However I am facing issue in adding the namespace attributes to the root element Position.

Java class is :

```
        @XmlRootElement(name="Position")
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public class Position{
    
             @XmlElement(name="Info")
             private String info;
    
    }
```

and the jaxb code is:

```
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Position.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            StringWriter wr = new StringWriter();
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, wr);
            String output = wr.toString();
```

The output generated is of the form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Position>
    
    <Info>
    ....
```

However I need the output as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Position xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://cmds.wlb3.nam.nsroot.net/xmlschema/ArkRioPositionSchema/v1">
  
  <Info>
   ...
```

How can I add those xml namespace attributes to the root element. Please any help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You add the namespace by actually specifying the namespace on the annotations:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Position", namespace = "http://cmds.wlb3.nam.nsroot.net/xmlschema/ArkRioPositionSchema/v1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Position{

    @XmlElement(name = "Info", namespace = "http://cmds.wlb3.nam.nsroot.net/xmlschema/ArkRioPositionSchema/v1")
    private String info;

}
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Position xmlns="http://cmds.wlb3.nam.nsroot.net/xmlschema/ArkRioPositionSchema/v1">
    <Info>Testing...</Info>
</Position>
```

The `xsi` and `xsd` namespaces will be added if they are needed, and this example doesn't need them.

Note that instead of having to specify the namespace on all the annotations, you can also specify the namespace for the entire java package, by adding an annotation in a `package-info.java` file. A bit of research will quickly teach you how.

Comment: Thanks for you reply , but when I try to add it, I get the output as 

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Position xmlns:ns2="http://cmds.wlb3.nam.nsroot.net/xmlschema/ArkRioPositionSchema/v1">
    <ns2:Info>` 
 
How can I get rid of this ns2 at multiple places

Comment: @Aadil Why do you care? Namespace prefixes are local to the XML document, and any code reading the document shouldn't care what the prefix is. If they do care, then they are broken and should be fixed. Only the namespace URL matters, the prefix is just a local *alias*, so you don't have to repeat the long URL all over. --- Anyway, you *can* control the prefix in use. Since I don't see why I should do your *research* for you, I recommend you do a web search for [`jaxb namespace`](https://www.google.com/search?q=jaxb+namespace) and read some of the articles you find.

Comment: Sure Andreas, I am researching on this fix since morning, Actually I am publishing this xml payload to an external system which unfortunately complains about the missing xmlns tag and is failing. As I don't have control to correct that code . So I need to fix mine only. Thanks for your help anyway..appreciated

Comment: @Aadil *"complains about the **missing** `xmlns` tag"* I don't know the exact error, but I bet that is wasn't complaining about the prefix, but about the fact that your XML didn't have a namespace at all.